# Upscale before or after doubling framerate?

Tags: fps

I use both Topaz AI (to upscale the resolution of the frames) and Flowframes (to double the FPS), but I'm interested in knowing whether the order of these 2 operations will affect the final result if you have any idea or a technical detail to share about this ? Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this answer is a bit of trial and error. But Imho is a way better option to upscale the images before and double the frames after.

My tests with Flow frame showed me some glitches when two moving objects intersected. It was a 3D animation, so there was no motion blur. This shows me that the "guessing" that needs to do and analyze is way more than an upscaling. You do not want to amplify any imperfection that the process does.

Although we now have AI algorithms to upscale, it is a process that have being done for years, and it is more simple. So do this process that needs to "guess" very little. Then do the second one with "reliable" pixel data; invented but reliable.

Comment: I see your logic. Thank you very much for your answer.